# How to find the weight details in solr query

Tags: solr, solrj, relevance

I found the query for getting the data from solr using the relevance boostage.

```
localhost:8983/solr/MYCORE/select?q=*:*&debugQuery=true
```

What I want is a way to identify the solr weight , so that I can identify whether the query result is correct.

Answer (score 2):

@Joju Just add this to your URL `debug=true&defType=edismax`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you want to say score instead of weight. You can find scores in the **section explain** of your return.

But with your query, you will see only score as below :

```
1.0 = (MATCH) MatchAllDocsQuery, product of: 1.0 = queryNorm
```

To have scores more useful, do a more precise query.

And to understand how the score is calculated, use [Lucene Doc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/scoring.html).